# "git pull" stopped merging automatically

Tags: git, merge, pull

The behavior of `git pull`has recently stopped automatically merging my currently checked out branch. I have to call `git merge` every time after I pull. If I run `git pull origin branch_name` it merges fine.

Here's the relevent parts of my config file.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    editor = /bin/vim.exe
    autocrlf = true
    whitespace = --get
    bare = false
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[merge]
    edit = no
[pull]
    edit = no
[merge]
    edit = no
[branch "branch_name"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/branch_name
```

Comment: What version(s) of Git were you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.8.3

Answer (score -2):

Have you upgraded your git version from 1.X to 2.X?

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional `matching` semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: This almost feels like an answer, but is more asking a clarifying question than anything else.  If you could make this more objective, then it'd be fine as an answer.

Comment: I'm running git 2.8.3